# Displaying results of Ember Data find

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the DS.RestAdapter, revision 12 to query a server for results but I'm struggling to display the results on the page if I query more than once.

I have an application with a search Button tied to the following action:

```
search: function() {
  this.set('searchResults', App.Property.find());
}
```

Then in my handlebars template I have code for displaying the results, similar to this:

```
{{#if searchResults.isLoaded}}
  {{searchResults.length}}
{{/if}}
```

With this configuration, every time I click the search button, a JSON request is made, all the Properties are retrieved and displayed on the screen. The searchResults object is of type: DS.RecordArray and the reference to the object seems to remain constant. ie.. if I display {[searchResults}} on the template, I get   and the ID stays the same.

However, as soon as I change my code to query based on parameters, for example:

```
search: function() {
  this.set('searchResults', App.Property.find({hello: 'world}));
}
```

Then, every time I click the search button the query is made to the server with the correct search parameters, and the first time I do this, the search results are displayed correctly on the page..... but .... as soon as I click search again, the results disappear. In addition the searchResults object is now of type: DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray  and if I show it on the screen, I can see that {{searchResults}} gets a new instance every time I click search, however the isLoaded property is always false, and so my results don't display.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF anyone experiences something like this, the problem was being caused because I had overwritten the didLoad function on the objects that I was loading. In the didLoad function I was checking to see if an associatio was empty and if it was, I was creating a new instance of the allocation locally on the browser.

This seems to mess with the 'isLoaded' status of the entire array of Objects that I was loading.